# How to bind event after ajax success in jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

So here is my code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#form').bind('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'api.php',
    data: 'task=getdirs&formname='+$('#form').attr('value'),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (html){
        $('#chdir').html(html);
        $('#chdir select').bind('change', getDirs());
        }
    });
});
function getDirs(){
}})
```

`#form` here has a `<select>` element. The ajax call returns a piece of html with a new `<select>` element.
It works nice: in the `#chdir` div I get a new dropdown element. But the event inside the `success` part fires only once. Then this event does not work anymore at all.
What can I do to make the newly created `<select>` element work in the same way as the first?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are invoking the `getDirs` function directly on the `bind` method call, you should only do it if this function returns another function, but I think that's not the case.

Change:

```
$('#chdir select').bind('change', getDirs());
```

To:

```
$('#chdir select').bind('change', getDirs);
```

Or if you are using jQuery 1.4+, you can bind the `change` event with the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method only once, and you will not need to re-bind the event after that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#chdir select').live('change', getDirs);
});
```

Comment: I have a question. hope you can helpme. the question is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276079/

Comment: Careful with the live method. In the jquery 1.7 is deprecated and in 1.9 is removed (http://api.jquery.com/live/). (I know it is a very old question but searching about the same problem I have reach here)

Answer (score 3):

Because this SO post came up in my google search, I thought I should mention that `.live` has been deprecated as of 1.9, and the recommended method is now `.on`

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the problem is with the event not working with your dynamically created select element.

If so, the solution is simple...try this:

```
$('#form').live('change', function()...
```

**Update:** With newer versions of jQuery you have to use `on()` instead of `live()`.

Comment: This will make sure that the event gets bound every time.

Comment: Updated to mention on() is the new way to do it with recent jquery api changes

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery 1.9+, [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method should be used to attach event handlers. However, after appending HTML to document you still have to attach new event handlers.

To write small piece of simple, working code and handle new elements you can use `.on` on document:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close-icon', function() { // selector as a parameter
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500); // - example logic code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using bind, try using [.live](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1751-jQuery-Live-Method-And-Event-Bubbling.htm). You'll need the latest version of jQuery to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery API:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

So you should use .delegate() if you are working with a jQuery version previous to 1.7.

http://api.jquery.com/live/