# How to handle nested events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, nested

I have a

```
<span class="fold"></span>
```

that's handled by a

```
$('.fold').click(function (event) { ... });
```

Now the click event adds new "fold" classes through ajax that I would like to assign the same event handler to. Is that possible and if so where in the logic would I "re"-add my click handler?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319790/how-to-bind-event-after-ajax-success-in-jquery

Comment: The concept you are after is called _event delegation_ and there are a few ways to do it (some depending on which version of jQuery you are using). The more efficient usage of event delegation requires more knowledge of your markup since it involves adding the event handler to the closest common ancestor to your `class=".fold"` elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are dynamically adding elements which require handlers, use a delegated event handler like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fold', function(e) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Note that for best performance you should replace `document` with the selector of the element which the `.fold` elements are being appended to.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks a million :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just write:

```
$(".fold").on("click", function(event){
  //write code
});
```

Update: For dynamically appended elements write this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fold', function(e) {
    // write code
});
```

Comment: This is equivalent to what the OP already has, and won't work on dynamically appended elements

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Why it won't work on dynamically appended elements?

Comment: @Arvind07 you'd need to add it to the elements somehow, _after_ they are appended

Comment: Because the `click` handler will only be assigned to elements in the DOM on page load. Any appended after load will not have the event handler unless you use `on` like in my answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are assuming this _is_ executed on page load.

Comment: You _can_ attach the event handler to new elements, but not by using this selector (as then the existing elements will have the event handler attached twice)

Comment: @JanDvorak true, I am assuming that, but it's a very common assumption to make unless the OP specifies otherwise :)

Comment: @CJe which one; the second one?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yup - first one worked like a charm, second one didn't

Comment: @CJe you mean the first answer? Because the second part of this answer is the same as the other answer.

Comment: @CJe Arvind's answer consists of two suggestions. The second suggestion is the same as the Rory's answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Sorry - didn't see Arvinds update - that would work too as it's identical to Rory's :-)